# How to simplify creation of null-safe Comparator on multiple fields?

Tags: java, java-8, comparator

I have this simple comparator which compares an Action object by its date and time fields:

```
static final Comparator<Action> COMPARATOR = comparing(Action::date, 
nullsLast(naturalOrder())).thenComparing(Action::time, 
nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
```

An example of the result is shown below:

```
{hour: 01/01/2019, time: 15:55}
{hour: 01/01/2019, time: null}
{hour: 03/01/2019, time: 11:11}
{hour: 08/01/2019, time: 11:11}
{hour: 08/01/2019, time: null}
{hour: null, time: null}
{hour: null, time: null}
```

The comparator needs to include three more fields.
Repeating `nullsLast(naturalOrder())` every time frustrates me to no end.

How could I simplify the use of the comparator without using a 3rd party library?

Comment: That's pretty simple already, no?

Comment: I simplified it for the question, i have multiple fields in fact and i have to pass `nullsLast(naturalOrder())` each time to the comparing method. It would be much more pretty if i can call it once for all comparing

Comment: I am thinking about Guava or Apache Common

Comment: Eh, we need to see your real code, if there's any hope of simplifying.

Comment: You could write a proxy method that takes in the compared Actions and returns the result of the compare operation.

Comment: So it sounds like you have a bunch of different fields you want to compare in a null-safe fashion, not just date and time? If so, add that to your question.

Comment: @StuartMarks null-safety is part of the question, the question is about enhancing the writing of the null-check

Comment: @RobertHarvey the real code is like the one posted here with three more fields

Comment: @AidanLovelace Yes i can write something like `MyComparator.comparingNullFirst(Action::date).thenComparingNullFirst(Action::time)` whitch returns `java.util.Comparator`

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've edited the question to include more details about what I think the OP is asking. Voted to reopen. I also have ideas for an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like your `Action` class has five fields, and you want to create a composite Comparator over all the fields, and that's also null-safe. You could do this:

```
    Comparator<Action> COMPARATOR1 =
        comparing(Action::date, nullsLast(naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparing(Action::time, nullsLast(naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparing(Action::foo, nullsLast(naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparing(Action::bar, nullsLast(naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparing(Action::baz, nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
```

If repeating `nullsLast(naturalOrder())` is frustrating, then one can create some utilities to help. First, we observe that `naturalOrder()` returns a singleton Comparator instance. It works for any Comparable type; all it does is call the `compareTo()` method.

The `nullsLast()` wrapper simply adds null checking before delegating to its wrapped Comparator. It doesn't depend at all on the actual type it's comparing. It's not a singleton, but any nulls-last-natural-order comparator is as good as any other. Thus we can create a single instance and reuse it. We wrap it in a method in order to avoid having to cast it to the right type at every use site.

```
static final Comparator<?> NLNO = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder());

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Comparator<T> nlno() {
    return (Comparator<T>)NLNO;
}
```

This lets us do the following instead:

```
    Comparator<Action> COMPARATOR2 =
        comparing(Action::date, nlno())
        .thenComparing(Action::time, nlno())
        .thenComparing(Action::foo, nlno())
        .thenComparing(Action::bar, nlno())
        .thenComparing(Action::baz, nlno());
```

Still too verbose? We can write a method that takes a variable number of accessor methods and creates a combined comparator based on them, by reducing over `thenComposing()`. That looks like this:

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
static <C extends Comparable<C>> Comparator<Action>
comparatorWith(Function<Action, ? extends C>... extractors) {
    return Arrays.stream(extractors)
                 .map(ex -> comparing(ex, nullsLast(naturalOrder())))
                 .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
                 .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("need at least one extractor"));
}
```

This enables us to write the following:

```
    Comparator<Action> COMPARATOR3 =
        comparatorWith(Action::date, Action::time, Action::foo, Action::bar, Action::baz);
```

Is it worth it? The helper method is probably more complicated than writing out a single chain of `nullsLast(naturalOrder())` calls. If you need a bunch of different comparator chains, though, then the ability to reuse the helper method might be worth its complexity.